# Cardinality, bijections, infinite sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We know that if there is a bijection from finite set $A$ to finite set $B$, we can remove one element from both sets and still be able to form a bijection.
Similarly, removing sets of equal cardinalities from finite sets still allows us to form bijections. But this result does not hold for infinite sets.

Let the removed infinite sets be $A'$ and $B'$, such that they are both proper subsets of $A$ and $B$ respectively.
Let $A=B=B'=\mathbb{N}$.
Let $A'$ be the set of odd numbers.
Then, $A-A'$ is the set of even numbers. The cardinality of $(A-A')$ is $\mathbb{N}$.
$B-B'= \emptyset$ so the cardinality of $(A-A')$ is not equal to $(B-B')$. Hence, I have proved that the finite set rule I described above does not hold for infinite sets. Is this correct?

Comment: what do you mean let $A=B=B'=N$, if the sets are equal in the first place, then why bother with any of this? Do you mean the cardinalities are equal? Also isn't B' a proper subset of B.

Comment: The first is statemenr is true for **non-empty** finite sets.

Comment: Because I have set out to prove that for infinite sets, cardinalities of (A-A') and (B-B') might not be equal, I am saying as a counterexample, that A=B'=B=N.

Comment: Seems correct to me.

Comment: Actually one small mistake. You say that $B'$ is a proper subset of $B$, but then you say $B = B'$. To fix this, you can just let $B' = \mathbb{N} - \{0 \}$.

Comment: Other example $A= \mathbb Q$ and $A' = \mathbb N$ and $B = \mathbb N + \{0\}$ and $B'= \mathbb N$.  Or $A = B = \mathbb N$ and $A' = \mathbb N \setminus \{1,2,3\}$ and $B' = \mathbb N \setminus \{1,2,3\}$.  Then $A - A' = \{1,2,3\}$ and $B - B' = \{1,2,3,4\}$.  But you should consider more variations and cases.  What if $|A| = |B| > |A'| =|B'|$.  Does the result hold or not.  How would you go about showing.